# Android expendable listview with same background either opened or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, mobile

I am trying to create an expendable listview which has same sort of background when it expends or not. i am attaching the picture too. I tried it with backgrounds but failed.

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView_tracks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="-10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbarX" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

[image: Expandable list view]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background of group if expanded or not expanded using your Adapter code like this:

```
@Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
   View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
  }
  ......

  if (isExpanded){
     // your group is expanded change background of main layout of your group row
   }else{
    // your group is not expanded change background of main layout of your group row
  }
  ........   
  return convertView;
 }
```

define id to your row_group main Layout and change the background of this layout.